# Change SSL Pinning mode on runtime in AFNetworking

Tags: ios, objective-c, ssl, afnetworking, certificate-pinning

We have a trouble with AFNetworking library when we check for SLL Pinning. We need to change SLL Pinning mode on runtime but changing doest not effect for some reason. For instance, we don't want to check sll pinning for first the request, but want for the other ones. Any help would be really appreciated.

Here is how we set the SSL mode dynamically with `willCheckForSSLPinning` variable;

```
if ([ConnectionUtil connectedToInternet]) {
    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];

    if (willCheckForSSLPinning) {
        manager.securityPolicy = [AFSecurityPolicy policyWithPinningMode:AFSSLPinningModePublicKey];
    } else {
        manager.securityPolicy = [AFSecurityPolicy defaultPolicy];   
    }
    ....
}
```

Comment: I didn't work on SSL Pinning but check below link it might be useful to you https://infinum.co/the-capsized-eight/how-to-make-your-ios-apps-more-secure-with-ssl-pinning

Comment: I've got the same problem. Did you find a solution?

Comment: i vote your question. I am in stuck just like you.

Comment: Trusting on First Use(TOFU) is highly dis-encouraged, from a security point of view. What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

use `[manager setSecurityPolicy: <yourSecurityPolicy>];`

instead of `manager.securityPolicy = <yourSecurityPolicy>;`